# Assigning float4 to float array opencl

Tags: c++, opencl

i am trying to optimize a simple opencl kernel using float4 instead of float.

This is the example code without float4.

example code:

```html
__kernel void Substract (
    __global const float* data,
    const float val,
    __global float* result
){
    size_t gi = get_global_id(0);
    float input_val = data[gi];
    result[gi] =  val - input_val;
}
```

My idea for float4:

```html
__kernel void substract (
    __global const float* data,
    const float val,
    __global float* result
){
    size_t gi = get_global_id(0);

    float4 val2 = float4 (val,val,val,val);
    float4 input_val = data[gi*4];


    result[gi] = val2 - input_val;

       }
```

However this does not work, because we can not write back a float4 result into a float array. Is there a performant possibilty to write back float4 to a normal float array in opencl? The simple idea would be a for loop with 4 runs.

I want to optimize the kernel for gpu and cpu.
So if i have a variant with float4 and one without, both should run under the excact same kernel arguments. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare your arguments as `float4` pointers, without changing anything on the host. Also, the compiler should automatically widen scalar values if they are used in expressions containing vectors, so you don't need to manually create a `float4` version of `val`:

```
__kernel void Substract (
    __global const float4* data,
    const float val,
    __global float4* result
){
    size_t gi = get_global_id(0);
    float4 input_val = data[gi];
    result[gi] =  val - input_val;
}
```